# Size of TableView in a VBox

Tags: javafx-8

I want a layout with a resizable chart at the top and a fixed size table at the bottom. I tried using a `VBox` with a `Chart` and a `TableView`, with `VBox.setVgrow` to ensure all the resizing goes on the chart. I know in advance I will only have 3 rows in the table.

However, the table firstly shows more rows than I have, and secondly, also resizes when I resize the main window.

I am using JDK8, update 31, on Windows 8.1/64-bit.

I'm setting up my stage like this

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());

    Node table = makeTable();

    VBox.setVgrow(chart, Priority.ALWAYS);
    VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.NEVER);
    VBox root = new VBox( chart, table);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

and the table is initialised like this (Note: all the stuff with `Color` is just to have some data to put in the table)

```
private static Node makeTable() {
    TableView<Color> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Color.ALICEBLUE, Color.CHARTREUSE, Color.GOLDENROD));
    TableColumn<Color, Double> col1 = new TableColumn<>("Red");
    TableColumn<Color, Double> col2 = new TableColumn<>("Green");
    TableColumn<Color, Double> col3 = new TableColumn<>("Blue");
    col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("red"));
    col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("green"));
    col3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("blue"));
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    table.getColumns().setAll(Arrays.asList(col1, col2, col3));
    return table;
}
```

Is there a way to resize the table to its content and fix it there?

I have tried `setMaxHeight` and `setPrefHeight` with `USE_PREF_SIZE` and `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` on the table with no effect

Comment: Can you try with a combination of minHeight and maxHeight. For example, `table.setMaxHeight(120); table.setMinHeight(120);`.

Comment: That did not work. Printing table.getHeight() shows that the height *is* constrained - but the layout seems to ignore this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the table firstly shows more rows than I have

This is the default style of `TableView`. you can hide them by customizing the css of table cell. But then another problem arises, the tableview will still show empty area where there is no rows. However both of these problems can be workarounded if the number or items (rows) are fixed. This can be accomplished by simply setting the preferred width and height of tableview:

```
table.setPrefSize( 300, 100 );
```

> and secondly, also resizes when I resize the main window

This is the default behavior of `VBox`. Here putting the tableview to another `Parent` that is not directly resizable, will resolve resizing problem. Most of time the good candidate is a `Group`.

```
Group group = new Group( table );
```

Additional visually laying out tips are:

- Align VBox children as centered: `root.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );`
- Give some padding to Vbox: `root.setPadding( new Insets( 15 ) );`

Full modifications to your code:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage )
{
    LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>( new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis() );

    Node table = makeTable();
    Group group = new Group( table );

    VBox.setVgrow( chart, Priority.ALWAYS );
    VBox.setVgrow( group, Priority.NEVER );
    VBox root = new VBox( chart, group );
    root.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER );
    root.setPadding( new Insets( 15 ) );
    Scene scene = new Scene( root, 300, 250 );

    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}


private static Node makeTable()
{
    TableView<Color> table = new TableView<>( FXCollections.observableArrayList( Color.ALICEBLUE, Color.CHARTREUSE, Color.GOLDENROD ) );
    TableColumn<Color, Double> col1 = new TableColumn<>( "Red" );
    TableColumn<Color, Double> col2 = new TableColumn<>( "Green" );
    TableColumn<Color, Double> col3 = new TableColumn<>( "Blue" );
    col1.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "red" ) );
    col2.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "green" ) );
    col3.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>( "blue" ) );
    table.setColumnResizePolicy( TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );
    table.setPrefSize( 300, 100 );
    table.getColumns().setAll( Arrays.asList( col1, col2, col3 ) );
    return table;
}
```

Comment: It also seems to be fine with `table.setPrefHeight(100)` and leaving the width alone.